# How can i synchronize the total number of socket.io client in both server in node js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-redis, socket.io-redis

I am using node js 4.2.6 version and using 1.4.5 socket.io version.I am using socket.io-redis module as the adaptor for socket.io. I am having two server with port 3000 and 4000. I added timer to print total number of connection sockets as below.

```
var socketio = require('socket.io')
var redis = require('socket.io-redis'),
io=socketio.listen(server); 
io.adapter(redis({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 6379 }));
setInterval(function() {
                console.log("The total sockets are:::::::::::::", Object.keys(io.sockets.connected).length);
            }, 5000 );
```

In one server I am getting correct client count , but in another I am getting 0.How can synchronize the socket.io clients between the server.

Comment: Why do you have two servers? AFAIK, `socket.io-redis` will not sync sockets/connections, it will allow you to reach clients connected to different servers (which are generally _physical_ servers).

Comment: Can you please provide me somce sample to code to get clients connected to different servers?

Comment: I think you'll need to implement some sort of coordination between your servers if you want to track the total number of clients connected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Socket Model and store the data ( in Mongo or Redis... whatever you're using ) so both server instances can request and access that information properly.

Answer (score 0):

When use https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis there are many things to do:

1. io.adapter.remoteJoin(socket.id, 'room_name_1', function(){}) // add a client to a room
2. io.adapter.allRooms(function (err, rooms) {}) // get all room
3. io.adapter.clients(rooms, function (err, clients) {})// clients.length count total client in all room.

Your code io.sockets.connected just count on one server (computer/machine)